# Database table to keep track of objects

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I have a table called `FoodMaker` and another table called `Settings`. Every `FoodMaker` has multiple `Settings`. I also need a 3rd table to record what has been made, when and with what `Settings`. It might have these fields: `id`, `food_made`, `date_time`, `settings_used`.

This is pretty straightforward since I can put IDs' of `FoodMaker` and `Settings` in the 3rd table to reference them. But the problem is, the `Settings` may change later but I want the `Settings` which the food has been made with and not the updated one. So I need to take a snapshot of `Settings` each time I'm INSERTING into 3rd table.

One easy way could be just to add all of the `Settings` fields to the 3rd table on each INSERT. But is it not redundant and ugly? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in your definition of the entity "settings".

If settings is a recipe, like "I made the hamburger id XX using Bob's recipe". If Bob's recipe is a record in a table, or the "settings" of the hamburger, then you should not just update it without keeping some sort of version control about it.

I believe the correct way to model this problem is to relate what "has been made" with a version of Bob's recipe, or "settings".

Keep everything that can change in a table related to the original Bob's recipe. There is more than one way to do this. Here's an example:

Hamburger A: id 1, settings 5, date 11/18/2014;

Settings 5: recipe Bob, delta-coffee +5ml, delta-sugar -1g; # (metrical units ml and g)

Recipe Bob: cream: 10 ml, coffee 10ml, whiskey 100ml; sugar  3g; (metrical units ml and g)